# React child component props are not updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render a component let say `Counter` to another component `Panel`  on its componentDidMount. I'm also passing a state called `count` as props to `Counter`. On certain interval, I'm updating the state. But the problem is the props of `Counter` is not updating. The prop still remains the initial value. What is the reason?

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Panel = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },

  tick: function() {
    setInterval(function(that) {
      that.setState({
        count: that.state.count + 1
      });
    }, 500, this);
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var panel = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.panel);
    React.render(<Counter count={this.state.count}/>, panel);
    this.tick();
  },

  render: function(){
    return <div ref="panel"></div>;
  }

});

var Counter = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return <p>{this.props.count}</p>
  }

});

React.render(<Panel/>, document.getElementById('container'));



<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

**I like to know the react reason why this code doesn't work**

JS Bin [check here](https://jsbin.com/qodakiniyu/edit?js,output)

Answer (score 1):

This code is bananas. Why are you calling `React.render` inside a component? Just render the counter in your `render` function.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var Panel = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },

  tick: function() {
    setInterval(function(that) {
      that.setState({
        count: that.state.count + 1
      });
    }, 500, this);
  },
  componentDidMount() {
    this.tick();
  },
  render: function(){
    return <div ref="panel"><Counter count={this.state.count}/></div>;
  }

});

var Counter = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return <p>{this.props.count}</p>
  }

});

React.render(<Panel/>, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: you are right. but I like to know why my code is wrong. does react creates owner ownee relation if you render a component inside componentDidMount?

Comment: It's wrong because you're missing the whole point of React. The only thing React is designed to do is to handle the rendering for you. If you are calling `render` manually, you are actively working against React.

Comment: I didn't know that, Thanks. I came across this issue when I try to load components dynamically on a single container. How normally in projects this situation of dynamic children's managed?